# Maintain Perfectly Circular Corners on Variable-Height Element

Tags: css

I have a button with perfectly rounded corners; meaning, the button is 50px high and the border radius is 25px, making a perfect half-circle on either side of the button:

[image]

Achieving this with CSS is easy, provided you already know the height of the button (button height ÷ 2 = border radius).

But is it possible to maintain the perfectly-circular edges if the button's height increases dynamically (more text is added, for example)?:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just set the `border-radius` to something high, like `360px`.

```
div {
    height:50px;
    width:500px;
    background:red;
    border-radius:360px;
}
```

Look at [**this jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/NPKn3/) to see what I mean.