# border-radius for circle left and right with unequal width and height and variable height

Tags: html, css

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

As width and height are not equal setting `border-radius:50%` gives an oval which is not what I meant to achieve. 
Giving fixed size (like `border-radius:20px`) would work if the height was fixed but how can I get this to work with variable height?

Comment: I think this has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179105/maintain-perfectly-circular-corners-on-variable-height-element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set border-radius to a higher value:

```
border-radius: 9999px;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set the border-radius to 360px or higher:

```css
    div {
      height:80px;
      width:400px;
      border-radius:360px;
      border:2px solid #333;
    }
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

This way you will always have perfectly rounded corners.

source: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20179186/5940675)